# Problems with rsync and ssh-key

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync, vps, ssh-keys

I created a ssh-key to log into my CentOS VPS, altered the default port to 2020 and disabled password connection, so I can only log in this VPS using the key (that need a password to be unlocked). My machine runs Ubuntu 16.04.

I logged in the server and, as usual for the first log, it asked my ssh-key password. I prompted, everything ok. Made some tests, and them I tried, for the first time, to use `rsync` to transfer files to VPS's web server. I had open a new terminal window and issued the command:

```
rsync -azP -e "ssh -p 2020" /var/www/html/myfolder myuser@myhost:/var/www/html
```

The first time it outputed:

```
The authenticity of host '[myhost]:2020 ([myhost]:2020)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Warning: Permanently added '[myhost]:2020' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
```

I think it's strange. Why it had to add my key again? And why `rsync` couldn't connect? When I try now I receive the same connection denied message (not the key add message anymore). Can someone put a light on it?

**UPDATE:**

**Command I use to log into the server:**

```
ssh myuser@myhost -p 2020
```

If it is the first connection, it asks for ssh-key password.

**VPS /etc/ssh/sshd_config (without comments):**

```
Port 2020
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication no
AllowUsers myuser root
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
X11Forwarding no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

**If I'm running both users with the same user:**

I didn't understand this question... =\

**Where are the keys?**

Well, I'm a newbie in ssh, I just had generated the keys with the command `ssh-keygen`, so I'm pretty sure the keys were in the default folders. And they're working, because I can connect with the VPS.

**-VVV mode:**

```
sudo rsync -aPvvv -e "ssh -p 2020" /var/www/html/curriculum/ myuser@myhost:/var/www/html

opening connection using: ssh -p 2020 -l myuser myhost rsync --server -vvvlogDtpre.iLsfx --partial . /var/www/html  (12 args)
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]
[sender] _exit_cleanup(code=12, file=io.c, line=226): about to call exit(255)
```

Comment: post the command you are using to connect to the server. Also potential `~/.ssh/config`.  Are you running both users under the same user? Where is the key you are using for authentication? What do you get with `-vvv` switches to `ssh` in `rsync` command?

Comment: Updated with the info you asked :)

Comment: You are running the `rsync` command under `sudo`, therefore under different user, who can not find your authentication key.